# Any 'quick' way to test which of 50 variables affects 1 dependent variable?

Tags: anova, categorical-data, factor-analysis

I've very rusty with my statistics. I know I can test each one by one.

But is there a quicker test?

Specifically, I have a list of 300 clients with a "contact rate" (dependent variable).

If I have 50 potentially variables to test, and don't want to just test the "logical" ones (maybe one is surprising) -- what's a quick way to test them all?

I know something like an ANOVA would potentially try to build a model with all 50. Maybe that's the best way; maybe that's folly.

Many of the variables are categorical as well.

Comment: If you are interested in the effect of the variables as a whole (without it's levels) then an ANOVA is appropriate.

Comment: Search our site for "Lasso."

Answer (score 3):

Offcourse there are many options and without a more specific question with respect to purpose or nature of the data I think I will simply recommend the good old workhorse: Linear regression.

And it never hurts to look at a correlation matrix (but that is down the line of testing each variable in isolation).

Comment: Yes I'm definitely rusty and a laymen with some of this stats stuff (took a few courses in college and a lot of math but amateur compared to here). I'll stick with regression and look into correlation matrix. The nature of the data is exploring: contact rates for various clients. That is a dependent variable. The rate is simply contacts/ orders. Obviously, if a product/ service is more expensive or "buggy" - it will have more contacts. There are less obvious ones though. Self-service options. Refund policy. Website features. Business vs. consumer. Vertical. Country. Product quality.

Comment: Auto-renewal is a another one (for subscriptions - obviously that spikes contacts). So mostly categorical variables --- the spread is huge and there is a lot of noise in all these rates. They even change month-to-month over different products if the client website is trash or they introduce a bug. But it would be interesting to know which variables are strong, which are non-factors (industry/ vertical is actually a non-factor IMO, every product has smooth operators and crap operators).

Comment: as a first try I would also suggest to model the situation using a linear regression. with $p=50$ variables a best subset selection is nowadays feasible (see for example https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.01454 and its introduction for more state of the art algorithms). however, in any way you should be clear about your goals: are you interested in variable selection or in prediction?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your software, it is probably possible to make the software loop through all the variables. This is not, however, a very good idea unless precautions are taken (one possible precaution is to have a train and test set of data). EDIT: I am assuming that you are not interested only in this specific set of 300 people, but in inferring to a larger group.

Even if everything was random noise, you'd get some relationships, by chance.

And "which variable" may not be the right question.

Comment: Could you explain why the OP would need a train / test set? His aim does not seem to train a model, as he is just interested to identify associations in the data.

Comment: Because even when you are not training a model, you probably are not interested just in the specific sample that you have.

Comment: Hmm I don't quite agree with this. I can think of countless examples where one might be interested in finding significant associations with between a set of variables and a response. For example, one might want to test whether a set of bio markers or mutations is associated with a certain phenotype. What's the benefit of splitting data into two subsets in this case?

Comment: You avoid over reliance on a particular sample. Each sample has its oddities.

Comment: Sure, but I don't see how this issue is solved by splitting the data. 

Say I'm testing for a significant association using a piece-wise statistical test on all markers and the response, how would a hold-out set benefit me in the analysis?

Comment: I see your point that each sample has it's oddities and that one likely finds 'significant' associations just by chance when testing for multiple variables, but here multiple-testing p-value correction or confidence estimation using bootstrap or the like seems more appropriate.

Comment: If what you find in the training data is similar in the test data, that's a good indication that it is NOT an oddity. Bootstrap could work too .... I didn't say train/test was the only way

Comment: I see where you are coming from, but I don't think that this approach makes much sense in this context. If I want to test the null hypothesis that two variables are associated, the is no reason to not use all available data. Tests assume that I have a finite set of observations from a unknown distribution, so they account for these 'oddities'. Splitting the data would IMO just lead to less power without adding any benefit, as the implied requirement that a association must be significant in both a training and test set can simply be done by adjusting the p-value calculated on the entire set.

Comment: I'm happy to continue this discussion in chat, as this might get a little bit off-topic.

Comment: i would be happy about a discussion topic on this matter.

Comment: Maybe it should be a separate question on the main part of the site.